# Angular CKEditor5 - Poor performance when loading multiple editors

Tags: ckeditor, angular7, ckeditor5

I am creating a "Quiz maker", that has a quiz description, questions and alternatives, where each field has its own ckeditor instance.

When the quiz has a lot of questions, sometimes it takes almost a minute to load the entire page. I need some code sample to initialize each editor after clicking on it and destroy it on blur event. So far I have something like this:

```
<ckeditor   (blur)="saveQuiz()" 
            (ready)="onReady($event)" 
            [config]="ckconfig" 
            [editor]="editor"
            [(ngModel)]="quiz.description">
</ckeditor>
```

This code is used in other places at the same page to load questions, alternatives, etc.